# HTML Table => option tags in different cells

Tags: html, html-table, html-select

I have a select element in html with option tags in it, but I want the single option elements in different table-cells like this:

```
<table>
 <select>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <option></option>
        </th>
        <th>
            <option></option>
        </th>
    </tr>
 </select>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not a valid html code. `<select>` element can contains `<option>` elements, not `<tr>` or `<th>` elements. What do really want to achive?

Comment: I know that this isn't valid html. My question is if i can put the different option tags from a select element in different table cells. So i want to have a table with the different options of the select element inside the <th> elements.

Comment: no. create a `select` element too in every `th` or use `radio buttons` or `checkboxes`.

Comment: Oke its impossible.. [image pickder](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) <= this is what i want to accomplish but i want the different images to get in table cells is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid HTML and, as far as I know, no browser will do anything useful with it.

If your goal is to have a collection of items arranged in a grid that the user can pick from then use checkboxes or radio buttons with labels.

Use appropriate markup (which might be a table, but it is impossible to tell from your lack of example data, use CSS if you want a grid but your data isn't tabular in nature) to structure it.